# Alternate rabbitmq-server restarts fail - CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos-7

I have installed rabbitmq-server on a CentOS7 Virtual Machine. After the installation is done. I tried restarting the server. I noticed that every restart after a successful restart is failing. I can't seem to understand why this would happen?

I did not notice anything unusual in the logs either. Is there something else I need to look at?

`[~]# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):  Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[~]# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):                [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):  Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[~]# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):                [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):  Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[~]# service rabbitmq-server restart
Restarting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):                [  OK  ]`

When I ran the 'journalctl -xn' command this is what I am seeing for when it fails

`su[5976]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user rabbitmq by (uid=0)
su[5976]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user rabbitmq
rabbitmq-server[5898]: Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
rabbitmq-server[5898]: rabbitmq-server.
systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker.`

There is nothing logged to 'startup_err' log and rabbitmq-server actually successfully starts.

I tried looking around the web to see for possible issues but could not find anything helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out be an issue with SELinux where the rabbitmq process was not able to create the pid file in the appropriate location if anyone was wondering.